# Do I need provide translation for an UI library

Tags: android, libraries, github, ui, localization

I have a library for a lockscreen in Android, that includes diferent dilogs for fingerprints, texts and all that stuff. My question is: What the best practice to provide localization. Should I have instuments that provides developers eho use this library to set up localization outside of library, which means if developer wants to support different languages it will be necessary to set up all the strings that being used in the library.

Or should I add localiation for those strings inside tha app?

To have better idea: https://github.com/thealeksandr/PFLockScreen-Android

Comment: Given that there are several thousand languages, how many are you intending to support and what would you do if someone asks for a language that you do not (yet) offer?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau well developer can add Pull request for the necessery language. This is actually what happened that makes me think about that. Another dev created PR with German support. So feels like kinda heavy to have it all in the lib. But also it's kind of wierd when you can not use library right from the box.